# Is there a built-in function in Meteor for email validation?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to perform user login (which is an email) validation on a server side. I could use some external `npm` packages or make something up with `regex`, but I'm curious whether `Meteor` has a built-in solution for this.
I didn't manage to find it in docs

Comment: There's none built-in.

Answer (score 1):

There isin't so called built in , but you can achieve so by using simple JavaScript function and with the help of [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
 if(re.test(email)){
    alert('Seems valid email');
 }else{
   alert('not valid email');
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="validateEmail(this.value)" placeholder="Enter email" />
```